# Deleting Telescope entries in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-telescope

i have telescope in my Laravel setup, I forgot that I have it and forget to prune it daily. So it accumulated a huge data already it has 28million entries and it is taking 30GB worth of space.

I tried to use both `php artisan telescope:clear` and `php artisan telescope:prune` commands but I was having a timeout error because of the large dataset.

How can I clear Laravel Telescope?

Answer (score 6):

three tables  that handle telescope operations namely — 
`telescope_entries`, `telescope_entries_tags`, and `telescope_monitoring`

in your database run these queries to empty tables

```
TRUNCATE TABLE telescope_entries;
TRUNCATE TABLE telescope_entries_tags;
TRUNCATE TABLE telescope_monitoring;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first run `php artisan telescope:clear` and then optimize the telescope_entries table `optimize table telescope_entries;`
As you have lot  of data it might take some time to process.

Comment: OP already used `telescope:clear` ... "_but I was having a timeout error because of the large dataset._"

Comment: Could you try deleting entries directly from the database tables?

Answer (score 0):

First get create table script of "telescope_entries_tags" then drop it. Truncate telescope_entries and run create table script of "telescope_entries_tags"